# How to use React's context API outside of react's component scope : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules, setstate, react-context

I am using react's context API for storing USER_TOKEN  for authentication purposes.

Also I am maintaining a common fetch function in a separate module where I want to use this USER_TOKEN.

And Its obvious that I cannot use this USER_TOKEN inside this module as it is not a react component.

Is there any way I can use this USER_TOKEN inside this fetch function.

I am storing USER_TOKEN into a context API variable after successful sign-in. Yes I know we could pass the variable from context whenever we call this function. But the thing is , Any change in the future will have to change it in all places. So I was wondering If there is only one place where I can do this. Basically the idea is sending this token along with all the API requests, so trying to maintain a common place.

Help would be appreciated

### Fetch Module

```
export module FetchModule {
  export async function fetch(obj: any) {
    let url = obj.url;
    let type = obj.type ? obj.type.toUpperCase() : "GET";
    let options: any = {};
    options.method = type;
    let idToken = obj.token;// Want to retrieve this USER_TOKEN from react's context API 
    if (idToken) {
      options.headers["USER_TOKEN"] = idToken;
    }
    options.headers = { ...options.headers, ...obj.headers };
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    return await response.json();
  }
}
```

Comment: One way would to store the token in local/session storage (depending on requirements) and get its value everywhere you need it

Comment: @AdamKosmala Would want to avoid local/session storage! Any other way?

Comment: can't think of anything that would not be a dirty solution right now. any reasons why not using browser storage?

Comment: you would need to pass on the token from where you are calling the fetch function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri The thing is , Any change in the future will have to change it in all places. So I thought If there is only one place where I can do this

Comment: @Adam Kosmala, Would not want to expose ! The only concern it should not involve the change in multiple places in case if there is any change

Comment: You can have a singleton class instance where you store the value and expose a function to get it. This you can use to get the value anywhere within your app. If you store it within context to cause re-render, you can update the value in class instance as well as context together

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri May be a simple code snippet would be really helpful here:) And I am storing this USER_TOKEN in my SignIn component once signed-in

Comment: @vr12 How did you end up solving this? I am facing a similar challenge. Need to access a value generated in the SPA from an imported module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a folder named: Context in the src/components folder
- in this folder that you have created (Context ) create a file named index.js
- in the index.js file write:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext();

export class Provider extends Component {


  state = {
    
      token: ''
    
  };
  
  setToken = (token) => {
  
    this.state.token = token;
    this.setState();
  
  };
  
  render() {
  
    return (
      
        <AppContext.Provider value = {{ 
    
                token: this.state.token,
                actions: {
                  setToken: this.setToken
                }

        }}>
    
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
  
      );
    
  
  }

}

exoprt const Consumer = AppContext.Consumer;
export const AppContextObject = AppContext;
```

- in the src/index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "./compomemts/Context/";
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider>
        <App  />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById("root")
);
```

- let's say you have login component, in it write down:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Consumer, AppContextObject } from "../Context";

class Login extends PureComponent { 



render() {

  return (
  
    <Consumer>
      {(actions, token) => (
      
        <button className="enter" id="enter-id" onClick={(event) => {
          if(token === undifined) {
            newToken = 'get the token from your system';
            actions.setToken(newToken);
          }
          
        }} >
                                connect
                            </button>
      
      )}
    </Consumer>

  )

}



}

Login.contextType = AppContextObject; // This part is important to access context values
```

```html
SuperAdminContextObject
```