# How to access React Context outside of component?

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to implement a function which gets called from within a functional React Component by a button.

It is supposed to delete a user from my own DB. But I need the access Token from Firebase to make this protected API call to my backend.

Now I'm serving the firebase instance from the Context API but I don't seem to be able to find a way to access this instance outside from a React Component.

I'm getting this error:

> Line 10:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Am I aproaching this the wrong way?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { PasswordForgetForm } from '../PasswordForgetForm/PasswordForgetForm';
import PasswordChangeForm from '../PasswordChangeForm/PasswordChangeForm';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization } from '../../services/Session';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../../services/Firebase';

const deletUser = (authUser) => {
  {
    firebase => {
      const token = firebase.doGetIdToken();
      console.log(token);
      axios.delete('/api/users/' + authUser.uid, {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
          //this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
          console.log(res);
        })
    }
  }

}

const AccountPage = () => (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => (
      <div>
        <h1>Account: {authUser.email}</h1>
        <PasswordForgetForm />
        <PasswordChangeForm />
        <button type="button" onClick={() => deletUser(authUser)}>Delete Account</button>
      </div>
    )}
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(condition)(AccountPage);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use React's context API outside of react's component scope : ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551741/how-to-use-reacts-context-api-outside-of-reacts-component-scope-reactjs)

Comment: `deletUser` isn't really calling any function, instead it is declaring a function that takes a firebase instance

Comment: Did you mean to have two sets of opening and closing curly braces in `deletUser`? (ie `const deletUser = (authUser) => { { firebase => ..... } }`)

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with the `const condition = authUser => !!authUser` syntax. Isn't this just setting it to "not not" itself?

Answer (score 2):

The code is declaring an anonymous  object, the inner syntax is incorrect

```
 const deletUser = (authUser) => {
  {//anonymous   object
    firebase => {//There is no key for the member of the object
      const token = firebase.doGetIdToken();
      console.log(token);
      axios.delete('/api/users/' + authUser.uid, {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
          //this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
          console.log(res);
        })
    }
  }//You never call or return anything of your object 

}
```